# Can I set Firefox to run unsigned applets easily?

Tags: firefox, applet

Is there any way that I can set my Linux box's firefox browser to run unsigned applet? This is an isolated testing machine. Can I set my firefox to be less secure, means can run any unsigned applets?

Im having problems in loading signed applets on my own local system with local html files.

Need advice.

Comment: What's "not easy" about it so far?

Comment: my write-to-file applet seems doesn't loaded from my html page. All my html,jar and class are located within same directory. But seems have problem, can't load.

Comment: This is a duplicate of your previous question: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/2055190/java-applet-doesnt-run-on-my-local-machine . It's generally best to update the old question with more information than to re-ask it.

Answer (score 0):

I think this is an issue with Firefox not allowing you to run applets from the file system.  If you have a web server on localhost and serve the directory up that way it works fine.  I'm not sure how you can change Firefox's configuration, but it's worth noting that other browsers don't have this restriction.  So if you have Safari or Opera installed, you can test with those.

Comment: My target is must use Firefox. I don't run any webserver on my local machine. Only FF and html file. I want to open my applet from my html inside FF. Thats all. But my applet seems don't want to load.

Comment: I'm saying I don't think you can.  I've had the same problem running local applets in Firefox.  It seems to be that Firefox is more cautious about this than other browsers and from my brief investigations I can't find a way to relax this security constraint.  You could use a different browser for local testing and then, once you've uploaded it to a web server, test the applet in Firefox.

Comment: I follow the steps from Signed Applets at java.sun.com. But somehow I got io exception. The applet runs, but it doesn't do the job.

Answer (score 0):

The signed/unsigned applet is more a function of the Java plugin than Firefox.  I'd suggest you sign your applet with a self-signed key.  You then just need to add your self-signed public key to the listed of trusted keys within the Java JVM.